# VirtualBox Windows 10 Client Runs Extremely Slow On macOS Catalina Host

Tags: windows-10, mac, virtualbox, virtual-machine, macos-catalina

I recently installed VirtualBox 6.1.10 and the latest Windows 10 Pro, along with the VirtualBox Extension Pack 6.1.10.

I've noticed that the virtual machine is extremely slow and the graphics feel slightly glitchy too.

My host machine specs:

- MacBookPro14,3
- MacOSX 10.15.5 Catalina
- Intel Core i7 @ 2.9 GHz base, 4 cores and 8 threads
- 16 GB RAM
- Radeon Pro 560 4 GB GPU

Windows 10 Client on VirtualBox specs:

- 3 processor cores
- 8 GB RAM
- Nested VT-x/AMD-V Enabled
- XBoxSVGA Graphics Controller
- 3D Acceleration Enabled
- VirtualBox Extension Pack 6.1.10 Installed

The logs can be found [here](https://pastebin.com/d9fuTDaS).

The virtual machine became so slow that I couldn't even shut down, instead, I had to resort to force quitting the VM application

What can I do to get a smooth and less-buggy experience?

Comment: What happens if you choose a generic video card and turn off 3D acceleration, any better?

Comment: With the VBoxSVGA controller and 3D acceleration disabled, the UI feels less glitchy, however, the performance is still very slow and it takes a long time even to just open apps like File Explorer. Any way I can make this faster?